# mongodb, node.js and encrypted data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, encryption, aes, bson

I'm working on a project which involves a lot of encrypted data. Basically, these are JSON objects serialized into a String, then encrypted with AES256 into a Cyphertext, and then have to be stored in Mongo. 
I could of course do this the way described above, which will store the cyphertext as String into a BSON document. However, this way, if for some reason along the way the Cyphertext isn't treated properly (for instance, different charset or whatever reason), the cyphertext is altered and I cannot rebuild the original string anymore. With millions of records, that's unacceptable (it's also slow).

Is there a proper way to save the cyphertext in some kind of native binary format, retrieve it binary and then return it to the original string? I'm used to working with strings, my skills with binary format are pretty rusty. I'm very interested in hearing your thoughts on the subject.

Thanks everyone for your input,

Fabian

Answer (score 4):

yes :)

```
var Binary = require('mongodb').Binary;
var doc = {
  data: new Binary(new Buffer(256))
}

or with 1.1.5 of the driver you can do

var doc = {
  data: new Buffer(256)
}
```

The data is always returned as a Binary object however and not a buffer. The link to the docs is below.

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/binary.html

Comment: Thanks, but it only answered half of my insecurity with binary. Guess I can save something in binary to the DB, but that still leaves the question of how to create a Binary cyphertext..

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher just crypt the data using the node.js crypto api's and save the resulting Buffer using the Binary class.